# Adjusting Excel Formula to reference itself within INDIRECT

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an excel document with multiple sheets that I am trying to count occurrences and display on a summary sheet.

My current working formula looks like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&T2:T5&"'!B3"),S2))
```

T2:T5 contains the names of the sheets to look at and count, S2 contains the value to look for.

In the code example above, I would like to modify B3 with the current cell it is in. I found a few solutions to obtain the value of itself but coming up short.

The solution I came across for obtaining the current cell:

```
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()))))
```

How can I combine these 2? or is there a better way? The whole point was to get the formula to play nice with autofill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&T2:T5&"'!"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),S2))
```

Comment: Lee - This is perfect, thank you! Seeing how this comes together was extremely helpful.